# UITabbar Customization with Colored Tab Icons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

I am facing a problem with creating a custom UITabbar with colored icons for tabs. I have been trying to find any custom control for that but unfortunately cannot so far. I have already search the StackOverFlow DB and it has nothing that matches my criteria. The only thing closest to my requirement has been a view with a bunch of button on the bottom but I need to do it through UITabbar Customization. Need some directions fellows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Hope [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45432200/WriteProject_CustomTabBar.zip) demo help you for what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the code @Neel. Actually using buttons have been an option I would rather not use as I have mentioned in the question as well. What I seek is actual customization.
But thanks for the code!

Comment: sorry to say but you can't get any other solution then this... 
also one thing if you can try to implement your logic in my code with image then you can make great app let me show you link of app i have developed http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cpr-for-clinical-photography/id517260326?mt=8 using this.
Here just one thing you miss is your personal logic and decision what to do you want every thing ready that's not possible...

Comment: Well, I guess that is the closest thing I can find to an answer then!

Answer (score 1):

The sample code available here will help you  https://github.com/aalittle/ALCustomTabBarController

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have checked it out already and it is not a very good control. It just gets a view and places it on top the Tabbar. Not the desired solution I am looking for.